# How can I filter data based on date and time?

Tags: javascript

I am stuck at filtering data **(array of objects)** based on the date which is in this format `(day(Sat), date(06) Month(Aug), Year(2021))` and the time is in this format `(06:30 AM)` this data I am getting from the server which I don't have access now I want to get data which has upcoming date and time.

I also search on Google and Stack Overflow about how to convert this date format in milliseconds so that I can put conditions in the filter but all in vain.

Here's the **arrayData**

```
arrayData = [
 {
   'title':'title1',
   'desc':'this is description',
   'date':'Sat, 06 Aug, 2021',
   'time':'06:30 AM',
 },
 {
   'title':'title2',
   'desc':'this is description',
   'date':'Sat, 13 Aug, 2021',
   'time':'06:50 AM',
 },
]
```

The filter method I tried looks like

```
arrayData.filter(data => {
  if(data.date){
    //condition no Idea about it 
  }
})
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! I don't understand how the date winds up in an array. Do you have an array of objects with the dates as strings in the `.date` property? Please show exact input structure and exact desired output structure. Thanks.

Comment: What is the *exact* data you get from your server, and what *exactly* do you want to do with it?

Comment: @ggorlen I have updated the question. and you are right its arrayData.date

Comment: Thanks, but what's the output supposed to be and why? I'd parse the dates with ```new Date(`${element.date} ${element.time}`)``` ASAP.

Comment: there are two dates available which are 06 Aug 2021 and the other is 13 Aug 2021 I want 13 Aug because its upcoming event

Answer (score 1):

A date is upcoming if it's value is greater than the value of the current date (now). You can get the current date with `new Date()`.

```js
let arrayData = [
 {
   'title':'title1',
   'desc':'this is description',
   'date':'Sat, 06 Aug, 2021',
   'time':'06:30 AM',
 },
 {
   'title':'title2',
   'desc':'this is description',
   'date':'Sat, 13 Aug, 2021',
   'time':'06:50 AM',
 },
];

let now = new Date();
let upcoming = arrayData.filter(o => now < new Date(o.date));
console.log(upcoming);
```